# Изменить код скрипта

Tags: javascript

Скрипт заработал, но не совсем правильно, а то есть наоборот сначала загружается версия css/weak-sighted.css а нужно чтобы сначала подгружались стандартные стили, помогите исправить пожайлуста!

Вот код скрипта

```js
var cssList = [
        'jquery.mmodal.css',
        'jquery.mnotify.default.css',
        'jquery.mnotifyajax.css',
        'mtooltip.css',
        'screen.css',
        'skin.css',
        'jquery.fancybox.css',
        'jquery.fancybox-buttons.css',
        'flash.css',
        'author.css'
    ],
    cssDisable = false,
    tmpCss = [],
    weakCss = '/weak-sighted.css',
    cssCookieName = 'css_disabled';

function isCssDisabled() {
    return cssDisable;
}

function cssAvailable(src) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cssList.length; i++) {
        if (src.indexOf(cssList[i]) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function disableCss() {
    $('link[type="text/css"]').each(function (i, el) {
        var $el = $(el), src = $el.attr('href');

        if (cssAvailable(src)) {
            tmpCss.push(src);
            $el.remove();
        }
    });
    attachCss('/weak-sighted.css', 'weak');
    $.cookie(cssCookieName, 1);
    isCssDisabled = true;
}

function enableCss() {
    $('#weak').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < tmpCss.length; i++) {
        attachCss(tmpCss[i]);
    }
    $.cookie(cssCookieName, 0);
    isCssDisabled = false;
}

function attachCss(src, id) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = src;
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    if (id) {
        link.id = id;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}

$(document)
    .on('click', '#normcss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isCssDisabled) {
            enableCss();
        } else {
            disableCss();
        }

    });

$(document).ready(function () {
    isCssDisabled = $.cookie(cssCookieName) || false;
    if (isCssDisabled) {
        disableCss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68150/discussion-on-question-by-msupreme---).

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что сработает, но попробуйте:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    isCssDisabled = $.cookie(cssCookieName) || false;
    if (isCssDisabled) {
        enableCss();
    }
});
```

**ATTENTION**: костыль!